# Applying stroke-dasharray style to only part of a path

Tags: d3.js, svg, nvd3.js

I have a run-of-the-mill nvd3 line chart. Sometimes the data represented by the chart is patchy. I would like to be able to style *part* of the lines differently to represent this, such as in this example:

[image]

Here, the dots are joined by a dashed line when far apart and a full line when close together. Is it possible to apply stroke-dasharray only to certain parts of a path, or do I have to trick nvd3 into creating a new line for each segment where the styling changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply stroke dasharray to part of a path, but you can create a very long stroke dash array that equals the length of your path and carefully calculate the locations of the dashes in JavaScript so that the dashes line up with the part of your path that you would like dashed.

Comment: This *almost* works and effectively answers the question, though I can't quite get it right until I figure out how to calculate the path length that corresponds to a given x axis position.

Comment: Segment path length is the square root of the sum of the squares of the difference between the two points coordinates: http://math.info/Algebra/Distance_Cartesian_Plane/

Comment: I ended up using another path element disconnected from the DOM to do length calculations (so it also works for interpolations that don't have straight segments). Thanks for your help!